# Why this structure don't have initializer and default values ? (transformer in Swift for tensorflow)

Tags: swift, initialization, swift-for-tensorflow

1. Structure `TransformerLM` doesn't init its member variables.Why this will work?
2. Structure `TransformerLM` doesn't have initializer or default value, why can  `let model = TransformerLM(contentsOfPythonCheckpointFile: checkpoint, config: config, scope: "model")` work ?

```
struct TransformerLM {
    var embedding: Embedding
    var positionalEmbeddings: Tensor<Float>
    var layers: [EncoderLayer]
    var norm: LayerNorm<Float>

    func call(_ tokens: Tensor<Int32>, states: inout [AttentionContext]) -> Tensor<Float> {
        let positions = (0..<tokens.shape[1]).map { Int32($0 + states[0].key.shape[1]) }
        let positionsTensor = Tensor<Int32>(shape: [1, tokens.shape[1]], scalars: positions)
        var h = embedding(tokens)
        h = h + positionalEmbeddings.gathering(atIndices: positionsTensor)
        for i in 0..<layers.count {
            h = layers[i](h, state: &states[i])
        }
        h = norm(h)
        let tmp = TimeDistributed(
            Dense(weight: embedding.weight.transposed(), bias: Tensor(0.0), activation: identity))
        let logits = tmp(h) // a somewhat hacky way to share weights
        return logits
}
```

git: [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift-models/blob/master/Transformer/Model.swift)
[call](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift-models/blob/master/Transformer/main.swift)

Comment: If you search for “TransformerLM” in your project then you should find a suitable  init method here: https://github.com/tensorflow/swift-models/blob/master/Transformer/PythonCheckpointReader.swift#L131

Comment: Thank you... I should have done this before...  Thank you!!